# ReactJS onClick event inside map function, then call parent's function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have just started to work with ReactJS and I can't figure out how I can make onClick events work inside a map function, which renders a few similar elements.
When I am not using onClick={this.someMethodName} in the child elements, everything is working fine, so I am guessing the 'this' keyword no longer refers to the parent.

Here is my code, which renders a simple menubar:

```
var SupplierBarComponent = React.createClass({
doSomething: function () {
    console.log("aaaaaaaah");
},

render: function() {

    const suppliers = this.props.data.map(function(supplier){
        return (
            <option onClick={this.doSomething} key={supplier.id}>{supplier.name}</option>
        );
    }, this);

    return(
        <div>{suppliers}</div>
    );

}
```

How can I make it work?
I have read a few similar questions*, but their solutions didn't work for me, or I couldn't make them work.

*:
[React onClick inside .map then change data in another sibling component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938026/react-onclick-inside-map-then-change-data-in-another-sibling-component)
["this" is undefined inside map function Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148827/this-is-undefined-inside-map-function-reactjs)
[Pass props to parent component in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639534/pass-props-to-parent-component-in-react-js)

Comment: If you console.log this in the map function is it return the component object?

Comment: Yes, it does. If I call it by console.log(this.doSomething) - so without ()s, it prints the function itself:
3models.jsx:9() {
        console.log("aaaaaaaah");
    }

If I call it with parentheses, it prints 'undefined' first on, but the function still gets called, and it prints out 'aaaah'.

Comment: Do you need to do `this.doSomething.bind(this)` ?? depending on your usage of this inside doSomething?  Also, you should get a synthetic event object that will include more information...

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working. I have checked it on this Fiddle.I just hardcoded an array instead of the props.

```
var Hello  = React.createClass({
doSomething: function () {
    console.log("aaaaaaaah");
},

render: function() {
        var data=[{id:1,name:'name 1'},{id:2,name:'name 2'}]
    const suppliers = data.map(function(supplier){
        return (
            <option onClick={this.doSomething} key={supplier.id}>{supplier.name}</option>
        );
    }, this);

    return(
        <div>{suppliers}</div>
    );
}
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/evweLre5/

Comment: Thanks for the effort for checking it out, it clearly does work in fiddle. So what could I be doing wrong on my local machine? I just have no idea where to look.

Comment: My first suggestion to you is start using ES6 convention for react code.

Comment: I tried it on my local also and it works absolutely fine.

Comment: Are you using babel?