# Filter JSON object to remove keys

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, arrow-functions

I have an Angular 2 app which gets some values from an API (which I can't control) using a promise.  The JSON returned is like this:

```
[{"Id":1053},{"Id":1054},{"Id":1103}]
```

However, my app only needs to consume an array of numbers i.e. what I need to consume is this:

```
[1053,1054,1103]
```

Here's the part of my app which gets the data from the API:

```
recordIds = [];

ngOnInit() { 
    this._contentService.getAncestorNodes(currentNodeId).then(
        (data) => {
            data.map(function(record){
                console.log('record.Id = ' + record.Id);
            });
        }
    );
}
```

I've tried adding `this.recordIds.push(record.Id)` into the `data.map` function to try to build a new object of just the Ids, but I just get the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'recordIds' of undefined
```

Question is, how can I take the response from the API and parse it into the desired format?

Many thanks.

Comment: Because `this` has different context in `map()`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, but how do I push to the `recordIds` array from inside the map function then?

Comment: Store reference to `this`. Or simply use the `return` of `map()`

Comment: I see from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148827/this-is-undefined-inside-map-function-reactjs that I can pass `this` as a parameter after the map function, and this sorts it. Thanks!

Comment: Or just use an arrow function.