# How to access a key value within State in a function?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to make a counter that adds up a total amount for items added to a webcart. I initialize this count within my `this.state` constructor. However, I'm having problems pushing a count total to it from a function within the same component. This is my `Cart` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {addCart} from './Shop'; 
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class Cart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {items: this.props.cart,cart: [],total: 0};
    }

    itemBucket(item) {
        this.state.cart.push(this.state.items);
        this.countTotal();
    }

    countTotal() {
        console.log(this.state.cart);
        this.state.cart.forEach(function(item, index){
            var total = this.state.total;
            this.state.total = this.state.total + item.price;
        })
    }

    ...

    render() {
        return(
            <div className= "Webcart" id="Webcart">
            </div>
        );
    }
}


...
```

In my `countTotal` function I want to push the total to `this.state.total`. Right now I'm getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined`. How can I push the count total to `total` in state?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React 'cannot read property of undefined' despite correct binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45010544/react-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-despite-correct-binding)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an arrow function so that `this` is preserved.

```
this.state.cart.forEach((item, index) => {
    // ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind your functions, to get access to `this` in functions body:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.itemBucket = this.itemBucket.bind(this);
    this.countTotal = this.countTotal.bind(this);
    this.state = {items: this.props.cart,cart: [],total: 0};
}
```

Comment: Ah! Right. Thanks.

Comment: And sure, don't forget context in `forEach`

Comment: Yeah I was just about to ask you that, how should I pass it to the `forEach` function?

Comment: `let self = this;
      this.state.cart.forEach(function(item, index){
           var total = self.state.total;
           self.state.total = self.state.total + item.price;
 })`

Comment: @feners you should use an arrow function as per Josiah's answer, and you do not need to bind your functions.

Comment: Yep, sure, the arrow function and variant with `self` from Nitin will help you, but without binding of functions is will not work, not sure why is someone downvoted my answer...