# handleClick while mapping an array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to map through an array and create links which will update state.  When I map through the array and create the links I get :

TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined

```js
var FilterList = React.createClass({
  handleClick : function(e, list){
          this.props.callbackFromParent(list);
                this.setState({showing : list});
            },
  render: function() {
          if(this.props.sdata ){
           var seasons ='';
            seasons = this.props.sdata.Seasons.map(function(season, i) {
              if(i < 30) {
              var playkey = season.mediaId;
              var name = season.Season;
          return (
             <li> <a href="#" onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, {playkey})}>{name}</a></li>
          );
        }else{
          return (<div key={playkey}></div>);
        }
      });
         return (
      <Row className="singleChannelSeasonsList">
        <Grid>
            <Col md={12}>
                <ul className="seasons">
                {seasons}
                </ul>
            </Col>
      </Grid>
    </Row>
    );
          } else {
    return (

      <Row className="singleChannelSeasonsList">
        <Grid>
            <Col md={12}>
                <ul className="seasons">
                <li><a href="#" className="activeItem" onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, "list")}>All</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#" onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, "category/Entertainment")}>Entertainment</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, "category/Health%20&%20Wellness")}>Health &amp; Wellness</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#" onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, "category/Opinion")}>Opinion</a></li>
                </ul>
            </Col>
      </Grid>
    </Row>
    );
   }
  }
});
export default FilterList;
```

How can I map through the data and generate the handleclick links.  {this} is bound and it works when i dont have this.props.sdata.  Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React 'cannot read property of undefined' despite correct binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45010544/react-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-despite-correct-binding)

Answer (score 1):

**The problem** is the value of "this" keyword is determined by how a function get called.
"this" is called inside of anonymous function in "map()". So "this" will be undefined.

**Solution:**

1. Bind() "this" to anonymous function

```js
  this.props.sdata.Seasons.map(function(season, i) {
    //....blah blah blah      
  }.bind(this));
```

2. Set "this" to the second argument of "map()" function

```js
  this.props.sdata.Seasons.map(function(season, i) {
       //....blah blah blah 
  },this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't bound {this} to `this.props.sdata.Seasons.map( () => {} )` yet!

It should be:

```
render: function() {
  if(this.props.sdata ){
    var seasons ='';
    seasons = this.props.sdata.Seasons.map( (season, i) => {
      //...
    });
  } else {
    //...
  }
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to bind this to your event handler:

```
...
onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
...
```