# How to map inside a map function in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have my table view.And i have posfields that are perfecting displaying by 
using map function.But my problem is when i'm trying to map td inside posfields map function its throwing me the error "'headers' of undefined".

```
{
  this.POSFields.map(function (posFields, POSFieldsId) {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td className="posheader" key={POSFieldsId} value={posFields.POSFieldsId}
          {posFields.POSFields} </td>
    <td>
          <select className="selectpicker">
            <option value="">Select Value</option>
            {this.headers.map(function (headers) {
              return (
                <option key={headers}>{headers}</option>
              );
            })}
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: Use arrow functions in both map functions `this.POSFields.map((posFields, POSFieldsId) => {`

Comment: This seems to be undefined inside the second map. Have you tried to change the functions passed to the map methods for arrow functions?

Comment: Ok, I'm late :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["this" is undefined inside map function Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148827/this-is-undefined-inside-map-function-reactjs)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React 'cannot read property of undefined' when using map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45010544/react-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-when-using-map)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Like @Andrew already suggested, you should use `arrow`functions in order to be able to access `this` within your map. You currently loose the context of `this`

```
{
  this.POSFields.map((posFields, POSFieldsId) => {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td className="posheader" key={POSFieldsId} value={posFields.POSFieldsId}
          {posFields.POSFields} </td>
    <td>
          <select className="selectpicker">
            <option value="">Select Value</option>
            {this.headers.map((headers) => {
              return (
                <option key={headers}>{headers}</option>
              );
            })}
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: just i tried using arrow fucntion as u said,Now its throwing map of undefined

Comment: Have you evaluated, that `POSFields` is an array? How do you declare your function? Did you bind your function?

Comment: Did you declare your function like so: `myFunction = () => {..}`?

Comment: My error is throwing at headers,and posfields is working fine

Comment: How does `headers` look like? Have you tried to `console.log(this.headers)`?

Comment: hey thanx guys,Arrow function helped for me,Thanq so much for your time :)

Answer (score 3):

Bind map function to have access to `this` context:

```
{
  this.POSFields.map(function (posFields, POSFieldsId) {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td className="posheader" key={POSFieldsId} value={posFields.POSFieldsId}
          {posFields.POSFields} </td>
    <td>
          <select className="selectpicker">
            <option value="">Select Value</option>
            {this.headers.map(function (headers) {
              return (
                <option key={headers}>{headers}</option>
              );
            })}
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    )
  }.bind(this))
}
```

Or the arrow functions `this.POSFields.map((posFields, POSFieldsId) => {`

Answer (score 0):

i usually use a function inside a function to return map func

```
{
  this.POSFields.map(function (posFields, POSFieldsId) {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td className="posheader" key={POSFieldsId} value={posFields.POSFieldsId}
          {posFields.POSFields} </td>
    <td>
          <select className="selectpicker">
            <option value="">Select Value</option>
            {this.getData()}
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    )
  })
}

getData(){
return this.headers.map(function (headers) {
              return (
                <option key={headers}>{headers}</option>
              );
            }}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the same as @Nocebo answered but with a little correction on the keys. They should be in the  tag rather in the  one below. If you open you browsers console you will see a warning about it:

```
{
  this.POSFields.map((posFields, POSFieldsId) => {
    return (
      <tr key={POSFieldsId}>
        <td className="posheader" value={posFields.POSFieldsId}
          {posFields.POSFields} </td>
    <td>
          <select className="selectpicker">
            <option value="">Select Value</option>
            {this.headers.map((headers) => {
              return (
                <option key={headers}>{headers}</option>
              );
            })}
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    )
  })
}
```