# Accessing state from within component React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components

I'm fairly new to react native and working on an app where I use a RkButton and then update the state when the button is clicked. The code is like this.

```js
render() {
    const { user } = this.props;

    let navigate = this.props.navigation.navigate;

    let items = MainRoutes.map(function (route, index) {
      return (
        <RkButton
          rkType='square'
          key={index}
          onPress={() => {
              this.setState({
                redeem: true
              });
          }}>
        </RkButton>
      )
    });

      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1,}}>
            <ScrollView
              alwaysBounceVertical
              overScrollMode={"always"}
              style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white'}}
              refreshControl={
                  <RefreshControl
                  refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                  onRefresh={() => this.handleRefresh()}
                  />
              }
              contentContainerStyle={styles.rootContainer}>
                {items}
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
      )
}
```

I get 'this.setState is not a function', since I've used the code from the UIKitten library I'm not entirely familiar with it. I'm pretty sure this is something to do with either ES6 or a misunderstanding on my part of how components work.

Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React 'cannot read property of undefined' when using map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45010544/react-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-when-using-map/45010580#45010580)

Answer (score 3):

You loose the Components context here:

```
  // Component context
  function (route, index) {
    // Functions context
```

Change it to:

```
  (route, index) => {
```

Comment: Aha! Ok, thanks! Is there any time you would want to lose the scope? Is it just for encapsulation?

Comment: @swimmingG you might want to loose the *context*
 (sorry for the confusion), for example in handlers when you want to refer to the clicked element. E.g. in jquery `$("a").click(function(){ $(this) /*!!*/ })`

Comment: Ah ok, so `this` when you use function (route, index) is then the button that was clicked. Thanks!

Comment: @swimmiG in this case it would probably be `window`, which is not really useful

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that function declared with keyword `function` have it own context `this`. You need to use arrow functions to have access to parent context:

```
let items = MainRoutes.map((route, index) => {
  return (
    <RkButton
      rkType='square'
      key={index}
      onPress={() => {
          this.setState({
            redeem: true
          });
      }}>
    </RkButton>
  )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a copy of **this** and use it inside any other function. whenever needed, as mention in line number 3.

so your code has some minor change

```
render() {
    const { user } = this.props;
    let self=this;

    let navigate = this.props.navigation.navigate;

    let items = MainRoutes.map(function (route, index) {
      return (
        <RkButton
          rkType='square'
          key={index}
          onPress={() => {
              self.setState({
                redeem: true
              });
          }}>
        </RkButton>
      )
    });

      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1,}}>
            <ScrollView
              alwaysBounceVertical
              overScrollMode={"always"}
              style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white'}}
              refreshControl={
                  <RefreshControl
                  refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                  onRefresh={() => this.handleRefresh()}
                  />
              }
              contentContainerStyle={styles.rootContainer}>
                {items}
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
      )
}
```