# Unable to display data of second array based on values of first array

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react , Below is state and render method for a component that has to display data of this.state.numberOfStarList  based on "item.full_name" ,
but I am getting error  - Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

```js
this.state = {
  error: null,
  isLoaded: false,
  numberOfStarList: [],
  objectDetails: []
};

render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {this.state.objectDetails.map(function(item) {
          return (
            <div className="col-md-6" key={item.full_name}>
              <div className="card">
                <img
                  className="card-img-top"
                  src={item.loggedInAvatar_url}
                  alt="user"
                />
                <div className="card-body">
                  <a
                    className="card-title"
                    href={item.html_url}
                    target="_blank"
                  >
                    <span>{item.full_name}</span>
                  </a>
                  <br />
                  <a
                    className="card-text"
                    href={item.loggedInHtmlUrl}
                    target="_blank"
                  >
                    <span>{item.loggedInOwner}</span>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
 {this.state.numberOfStarList.map(function(star){
                    return (
                        <h1>{star.key}</h1>
                    )
                })}
            </div>

          )
        })}

      </div>
    );
```

Comment: Use `.bind(this)` if you are not using arrow functions after the `}` of your first map callback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["this" is undefined inside map function Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148827/this-is-undefined-inside-map-function-reactjs)

Comment: Thanx ,It helped, but i am getting some weird output  -  while iterating -  "this.state.numberOfStarList",  for first  object keys of parent array are coming  fine like 0, 1, 2,3 but for second object of  "this.state.numberOfStarList"  keys are coming like  - 0,0, 1,1,2,2,3,3. Any suggestion? Is there any ckeck we have to apply

Answer (score 0):

Because you should define your states in the constructor and bind this for your function like the following:

```js
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     error: null,
     isLoaded: false,
     numberOfStarList: [],
     objectDetails: []
   };
}

render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {this.state.objectDetails.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div className="col-md-6" key={item.full_name}>
              <div className="card">
                <img
                  className="card-img-top"
                  src={item.loggedInAvatar_url}
                  alt="user"
                />
                <div className="card-body">
                  <a
                    className="card-title"
                    href={item.html_url}
                    target="_blank"
                  >
                    <span>{item.full_name}</span>
                  </a>
                  <br />
                  <a
                    className="card-text"
                    href={item.loggedInHtmlUrl}
                    target="_blank"
                  >
                    <span>{item.loggedInOwner}</span>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
 {this.state.numberOfStarList.map((star) => {
                    return (
                        <h1>{star.key}</h1>
                    )
                })}
            </div>

          )
        })}

      </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your confusion might be due to state being able to be declared in two ways.

## 1. Within constructor

Then you would need to use `this`.

```js
class Foo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        //  this is important as it makes other methods access props like `this.props...`
        super(props);    

        this.state = {
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            numberOfStarList: [],
            objectDetails: []
        }
    } 

    render () {...}
}
```

## 2. Declare state as a class instance variable

If you declare the `state` as a class instance variable (outside of constructor),
then you don't need `this`.

```js
class Foo extends Component {
    state = {
        error: null,
        isLoaded: false,
        numberOfStarList: [],
        objectDetails: []
    }

    render () {...}
}
```

So the gist is, if you are declaring the `state` outside of constructor, then you don't need `this`.

---

If you are using webpack, you need a Babel plugin, [babel-plugin-transform-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/), to enable class instance variable transpilation.