# Play video on mouseOver using JS in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, this

Just trying to get these videos to play on mouse over. I can see from the console I need to make a function instead of using a string (other SO answers use strings), so how can I do this without creating too much extra code? Ideally I want the functions set right on the onMouseOver & onMouseOut attributes.

```
        <video 
          poster="https://i.imgur.com/Us5ckqm.jpg"
          onMouseOver="this.play()" 
          onMouseOut="this.pause();this.currentTime=0;"
          src={`${vid.videos.tiny.url}#t=1`}
        </video>
```

Have also tried

```
        <video 
          poster="https://i.imgur.com/Us5ckqm.jpg"
          onMouseOver={() => this.play()}
          onMouseOut={() => this.pause()}
          src={`${vid.videos.tiny.url}#t=1`} >
        </video>
```

Which gives me the error: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined.

**Edit** Not sure this is relevant, but this code above resides inside of a map function, which is also part of a get request. Here is the full function:

```
  const fetchVideos = async (amount, category) => {
    const response = await axios.get('https://pixabay.com/api/videos/', {
      params: {
        key: '123456123456123456',
        per_page: amount,
        category: category
      }
    })
    console.log(response)
    const vidsAsHtml = response.data.hits.map(vid => {
      return (
        <div className={`${props.page}--grid-content-wrapper`} key={vid.picture_id}>
          <div className={`${props.page}--grid-video`}>
            <video className=".video"
              poster="https://i.imgur.com/Us5ckqm.jpg"
              onMouseOver={() => this.play()}
              onMouseOut={() => this.pause()}
              src={`${vid.videos.tiny.url}#t=1`} >
            </video>
          </div>
          <div className={`${props.page}--grid-avatar-placeholder`}></div>
          <div className={`${props.page}--grid-title`}>{vid.tags}</div>
          <div className={`${props.page}--grid-author`}>{vid.user}</div>
          <div className={`${props.page}--grid-views`}>{abbreviateNumbersOver999(vid.views)} 
            <span className={`${props.page}--grid-date`}> • 6 days ago</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
  })
  setResource(vidsAsHtml)
}
```

**Edit 2:** Seems like some other people had [problem with the 'this' keyword inside of mapping statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148827/this-is-undefined-inside-map-function-reactjs). Although I tried these solutions and 'this' is still undefined.

Comment: Is this your actual code? Cause if it is, you should pass a function to onMouseOver and onMouseOut.

`onMouseOver={() => this.play()}`
`onMouseOut={() => this.pause(); this.currentTime=0}`

Comment: Already tried that way -- gives me the console error Cannot read property 'play' of undefined

Comment: Closed it as duplicate of your other question (since it's about the same problem).

Answer (score 10):

A user named [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) gave a very simple answer that solved my problem in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59209874/2853450):

> Event handler props are expected to be passed a function. Currently
>   you are trying to pass the return values of `this.play()` and
>   `this.pause()` as event handlers, which wouldn't work anyway.
>
> Also React doesn't make the element available to the event handler via
>   `this`, but you can access it via `event.target`:
>
> ```
> <video
>   poster="https://i.imgur.com/Us5ckqm.jpg"
>   onMouseOver={event => event.target.play()}
>   onMouseOut={event => event.target.pause()}
>   src={`${vid.videos.tiny.url}#t=1`} >
> </video>
> ```

Find the working solution [here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-wwonj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Simple yet powerfull! Good one

Comment: wow, atleast it helped me achieve around 90 percnet of what is required

Comment: How about if we're using functions instead of classes?

Answer (score -3):

Some quick googleing and i found [this](https://codepen.io/gil--/pen/bNxZWg)

```
var figure = $(".video").hover( hoverVideo, hideVideo );
function hoverVideo(element) { 
$('video', this).get(0).play(); 
}
function hideVideo(e) {
$('video', this).get(0).pause(); 
}
```

this is however jquery so you must include the library in your html.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```