# react class component state data is not available under map function under render function

Tags: reactjs, this, react-props, react-state

I have a class component. on that component, I have a state item called **tasks_array**.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css';

import Task from './component/task'

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tasks_array: [
                {id: 1 , name: 'item 1'},
                {id: 1 , name: 'item 1'},
                {id: 1 , name: 'item 1'},
                {id: 1 , name: 'item 1'},
                {id: 1 , name: 'item 1'},
                {id: 1 , name: 'item 1'},
            ]
        };
    
        
        
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.tasks_array.map(function (item,index) {
                    return (
                        <Task
                            key={index}
                            myItem={item}
                            otherItems={this.state.tasks_array}
                        />
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

the error is popping up : TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

[image]

so the issue is in the line : `otherItems={this.state.tasks_array}` , where  **this** is **undefined** .

can anyone help me to understand, what is the reason for this issue ?

and how to solve this issue to send the whole **tasks_array** as a property of **Task** component

Answer (score 1):

["this" is undefined inside map function Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148827/this-is-undefined-inside-map-function-reactjs)

Array.prototype.map() takes a second argument to set what this refers to in the mapping function, so pass this as the second argument to preserve the current context:

```
someList.map(function(item) {
  ...
}, this)
```

Alternatively, you can use an ES6 arrow function to automatically preserve the current this context:

```
someList.map((item) => {
  ...
})
```

Comment: really thank you for the answer. really helpful.  can you help me to understand why es6 arrow function preserves the current state . any docs or something to read and understand.

Comment: sorry buddy i didn't downvote you :) Actually, i didn't know about this before as i've always used arrow function i never ran into this problem.

It's is a matter of understanding the "this"-keyword in javascript and what it refers to in different contexts.