# typeerror: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'handelChangeName')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to pass *handelChangeName* function to *oldList* component and *oldList* component must send data to *TodaybazarEdit* page. Here BoderList function **maping** *OldList* Component. But React says me **typeerror: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'handelChangeName')** problem.

Or any way you know please share.

Here is component....

**TodayBazarEdit**

```
import OldList from './OldList'

class TodayBazarEdit extends Component {
 
    handelChangeName (e, i) {
     
        console.log( e )
    }

    

BodertList(){
    return this.props.list.map(function ( object, i )  {
        return <OldList obj={object} key={i} onChangeName={ () => this.handelChangeName() } />
    });
}
    render() {
        return ( ... );
    }
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodayBazarEdit)
```

**OldList**

```
class OldList extends Component {

    onFieldChangeName = (e) => {
        this.props.onChangeName(e.target.value, this.props.index)
    }
   
    render() {
    
        return (
            <div key={ this.props.index } className='row' >

                <div key={`nameddsee ${ this.props.index }`} className='col-sm-4' >
                    <div  key={`namewe ${ this.props.index }`} className="form-group">
                        <label key={`nameeasdaw ${ this.props.index }`}  > Name Of Product </label>
                        <input  key={`namdsfdseea ${ this.props.index }`}
                            type='text'
                            className="form-control"
                            name='name'
                            defaultValue={ this.props.obj.name }
                            required='required'
                            onChange = { this.onFieldChangeName }
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div key={`nameallll ${ this.props.index }`} className='col-sm-4' >
                    <div key={`namea1 ${ this.props.index }`} className="form-group">
                        <label key={`name646e ${ this.props.index }`} > Amount Of Product </label>
                        <input key={`namefdfe ${ this.props.index }`}
                            type='text'
                            className="form-control"
                            name='amount'
                            defaultValue={ this.props.obj.qty }
                            required='required'
                            onChange = { this.onFieldChangeAmount }
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div key={`namersd ${ this.props.index }`} className='col-sm-4' >
                    <div key={`namerer ${ this.props.index }`} className="form-group">
                        <label key={`namsadsee ${ this.props.index }`} >  Amount Of Price </label>
                        <input key={`namesdadsae ${ this.props.index }`}
                            type='number'
                            step='0.01'
                            className="form-control"
                            name='price'
                            defaultValue={ this.props.obj.price }
                            required='required'
                            onChange = { this.onFieldChangePrice }
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>


        )
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(OldList)
```

Comment: `this` is undefined within the callback of `this.props.list.map` inside of `BodertList`. You can fix this by using an arrow function for the callback, which will put `this` within the correct scope. `this.props.list.map(( object, i ) => {`

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["this" is undefined inside map function Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148827/this-is-undefined-inside-map-function-reactjs)

Answer (score -1):

That's a lot of code, but skimming it - your issue appears to be that you're calling the function and passing its result to onChangeName. What you want is to pass the function itself:

```
// Change this line
return <OldList obj={object} key={i} onChangeName={ () => this.handelChangeName() } />

// To this
return <OldList obj={object} key={i} onChangeName={this.handelChangeName} />
```

Comment: The functions are not executed in this order. The first is defining a new function that will call `this.handelChangeName`. It's most likely an unnecessary step, but it is not calling the function and returning the results, they will execute at the time the OP expects.

Comment: So how to do this ? How to send data to parent component.